# Exact solution of a third-order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does anyone knows some exact solution of this nonlinear equation?

$f'''=af^2f'-bf'-C$

Thanks!

Comment: What is the independent variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved under some simplifying assumptions, start by saying $C = 0$, write the ODE as

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx} \left[ f'' - \frac{a f^3}{3} + bf \right] = 0.
\end{equation}

Integrate this equation. Set the constant of integration equal to zero. Now multiply the equation by $f^{\prime}$:

\begin{align}
f' f'' - \frac{a f^3 f'}{3} + b f^{\vphantom{}} f' &= 0, \\
\frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{f'^2}{2} - \frac{a f^4}{12} + \frac{b f^2}{2} \right] &= 0.
\end{align}

Integrate this equation and once again set the constant of integration to zero to give

\begin{equation}
f'^2 = f^2 \left[ \frac{a f^2}{6} - 1 \right].
\end{equation}

Rearrange and integrate both sides to give

\begin{equation}
\int \frac{df}{f \sqrt{\frac{a f^2}{6} - 1}} = x + \textrm{constant},
\end{equation}

I trust you can carry out the final integration and solve for $f(x)$.

Comment: thanks for the technique (though I think you confused $f$ and $f'$ somewhere).

Comment: @Uagi thanks for that, you were referring to an $f'$ that should have been an $f$ in the third equation?